# change the fontsize of the decimal number in Swift/ SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, watchos

So i need to make the decimal places smaller than the actual number i will show you what i mean below.

this is the code i have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BalanceDetailsView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var balance: Float
    var balanceString: String {
        return balance.formattedWithSeparator
    }
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                    Text(balanceString)
                        .font(.custom(K.fonts.gilroyBold, size: 24))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .padding(.top)
             
            }//:VSTACK
        }//:HSTACK
    }
}

struct BalanceDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BalanceDetailsView(balance: 43678)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}



//Formatter extension i used to get this code
extension Formatter {
    static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

        // minimum decimal digit, eg: to display 2 as 2.00
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

        // maximum decimal digit, eg: to display 2.5021 as 2.50
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension Numeric {
    var formattedWithSeparator: String { Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: self) ?? "" }
}
```

| Result I get | Result I need |
| --- | --- |
| [image: This is the result I get] | [image: This is the result I need] |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you know exact format of your string, like in this case minimum string length will be 4("0.00") , you can safely use `dropLast` and `dropFirst`.

I suggest moving `2` to `priceFractionDigits` constant to reduce constants usage in your code.

Then you can use string concatenation, it'll align `Text` by baseline.

```
struct BalanceText: View {
    var balance: Float
    var balanceString: String {
        return balance.formattedWithSeparator
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(balanceString.dropLast(priceFractionDigits))
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            +
            Text(balanceString.dropFirst(balanceString.count - priceFractionDigits))
            .font(.system(size: 18))
    }
}

private let priceFractionDigits = 2

extension Formatter {
    static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

        // minimum decimal digit, eg: to display 2 as 2.00
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = priceFractionDigits

        // maximum decimal digit, eg: to display 2.5021 as 2.50
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = priceFractionDigits
        
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Usage

```
BalanceText(balance: balance)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using the new `AttributedString` in SwiftUI 3 (iOS 15, macOS 12 etc)

```
var balanceString: AttributedString {
    var attributedString = AttributedString(balance.formattedWithSeparator)
    guard let separator = Formatter.withSeparator.decimalSeparator else { return attributedString }

    if let range = attributedString.range(of: separator) {
        attributedString[attributedString.startIndex...attributedString.index(beforeCharacter: range.lowerBound)]
            .font = Font.largeTitle
        attributedString[attributedString.index(afterCharacter: range.lowerBound)..<attributedString.endIndex]
            .font = Font.caption
    }

    return attributedString
}
```

I used some built in font styles here but that should be easy to replace. Also note that since we set the `.font` attribute here it should be removed from `Text`

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string by the decimal separator and display the parts in a zero-spacing `HStack`.

```
struct BalanceView : View {
    let balance : Float
    
    var body: some View {
        let components = balance
                        .formattedWithSeparator
                        .components(separatedBy: Formatter.withSeparator.decimalSeparator)
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 0) {
            Text(components[0])
            if components.count > 1 {
                Text(".")
                Text(components[1])
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

Replace the fonts with your custom fonts

---

In your environment you could use it

```
struct BalanceDetailsView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var balance: Float
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           BalanceView(balance: balance)
        }//:VSTACK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `Text` together with the `+` operator.

I slightly change the way you use `NumberFormatter`, so it's split by the correct decimal character for the locale.

```
struct BalanceDetailsView: View {
    private let wholeNumberPart: String
    private let decimalNumberPart: String

    init(balance: Double) {
        (wholeNumberPart, decimalNumberPart) = balance.formattedSplittingBySeparator
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(wholeNumberPart).font(.system(size: 24)) +
        Text(decimalNumberPart).font(.system(size: 16))
    }
}


extension Numeric {
    var formattedSplittingBySeparator: (whole: String, decimal: String) {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        let str = formatter.string(for: self) ?? "0\(formatter.decimalSeparator!)00"
        let split = str.components(separatedBy: formatter.decimalSeparator)
        let whole = (split.first ?? "0") + formatter.decimalSeparator
        let decimal = split.count == 2 ? split[1] : "00"
        return (whole: whole, decimal: decimal)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
BalanceDetailsView(balance: 43678)
```

Result:

[image: Result]